# Cannot schedule a runbook because of unknown job_schedule_id

Tags: python, azure, powershell, api, azure-cli

**Im trying to schedule a runbook on Azure programmatically.**

To do this it is necessary to create a runbook, then a schedule and finally to associate the runbook with the schedule. And this can be done in 3 ways (because it's not available on azcli): **API, Powershell or Python-SDK**

**Powershell**:

I did it with powershell in an easy and intuitive way. My runbook is called "my_custom_runbook", then I create the Schedule and finally I make the association using the name of the runbook and the name of the Schedule.

```
    # Create schedule 
    New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -Name "Daily" -StartTime $CurrentDate -DayInterval 1 -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup
    # Link Schedule to Runbook 
    Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -Name "my_custom_runbook" -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -ScheduleName "Daily"
```

**API**

Repeat the same process. First we create the Schedule using this call which has the same parameters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/rest/api/automation/schedule/create-or-update

**Here comes the problem**. When making the association, **a new parameter is requested: jobScheduleId**. The previous call has only returned a code 200. But if I run get() of the new schedule, the identifier is the name itself, so jobScheduleId is not related to Schedule. Let's continue...

**Python-SDK**

This is the same as in the API. The **job_schedule_id parameter is mandatory and no value is accepted**: None, "" or "random_string".

```py
CLIENT = AutomationClient(CREDENTIAL, SUB_ID)
    
    def create_schedule():
        params = {'name': 'Daily', 'start_time': datetime.today(), 'frequency': 'Day', 'interval': 1}
        return CLIENT.schedule.create_or_update(RESOURCE_NAME, AUTOMATION_NAME, 'Daily', params)
    
    def assign_runbook_schedule():
        params = {'schedule': {'name':'Daily'}, 'runbook': {'name': 'my_custom_runbook'}}
        job_schedule_id = '???????'
        return CLIENT.job_schedule.create(RESOURCE_NAME, AUTOMATION_NAME, job_schedule_id, params)
```

Am I missing something or is it really a bug in Azure?

BTW, I need to do it in API, Python or CLI because I need it to work cross-platform.

---

**Edit:**

I have discovered that the identifier is created on the fly, it is not an existing value and has this format: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.

If the identifier has been created before, it will give an error.
The problem is that these identifiers cannot be listed or deleted.

So it's basically a matter of luck.

```py
    CLIENT = AutomationClient(CREDENTIAL, SUB_ID)
    
    def create_schedule():
        params = {'name': 'Daily', 'start_time': datetime.today(), 'frequency': 'Day', 'interval': 1}
        return CLIENT.schedule.create_or_update(RESOURCE_NAME, AUTOMATION_NAME, 'Daily', params)
    
    def assign_runbook_schedule(job_schedule_id):
        params = {'schedule': {'name':'Daily'}, 'runbook': {'name': 'my_custom_runbook'}}
        return CLIENT.job_schedule.create(RESOURCE_NAME, AUTOMATION_NAME, job_schedule_id, params)

    def delete_job_schedule(job_schedule_id):
        return automation_client.job_schedule.delete(RESOURCE_NAME, AUTOMATION_NAME, job_schedule_id)
```

```sh
>>> assign_runbook_schedule('99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999')
    None #Assignement created
>>> delete_job_schedule('99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999')
    None #Assignement deleted
>>> assign_runbook_schedule('99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999')
        ...
        raise error
    azure.core.exceptions.ResourceExistsError: (Conflict) A jobSchedule with same id already exists.
>>> assign_runbook_schedule('33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333')
    None #Assignement created
```

When I run `delete_job_schedule()` I am deleting the runbook-schedule assignment but not the job_schedule object. That's why I can't create it again using the same `job_schedule_id`.

Comment: what do you mean with cross-platform?

Comment: I want to run it on any S.O.. Windows, Linux or Mac.  That's why I don't take the powershell example